# Median of list of difference of elements

Tags: algorithms, discrete-mathematics

I have a list. I have to find median of absolute difference of all pairs of array.

Eg - `A={1,2,10}`

Difference for all distinct pairs  :

1-10=9

1-2=8

2-10=8

The new list is `A'=[8,8,9]` and the median is 8.

Now I took all the pairs and made a list with difference of them and median is *A'.length()/2<sup>th</sup>* element i.e. 8.

But is there a way to do without taking all the pairs as the time complexity is *O(n<sup>2</sup>)* and I want to reduce the time complexity to *O(nlogn)* or less.

Comment: That's a nice (and challenging) exercise.  We're happy to help you understand the concepts but just solving exercises for you is unlikely to achieve that. You might find [this page](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1284/755) helpful in improving your question.

Comment: To give you something to start with, show that given a difference $D$, you can determine its index in the absolute difference array in time $O(n\log n)$.